# Сотню раз / Сотни раз

Tags: окончания

Не знаю, как будет правильно. Само выражение «сотни(ю) раз» довольно часто употребляется, и, как по мне, «сотни раз» звучит лучше. 
Не знаю, какое окончание выбрать вот в таком контексте: 
«Он уже сотни(ю) раз пожалел о содеянном».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Кузнецова допускаются оба варианта. Но это выражение отмечено как разговорное.
[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=сотня&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8F&all=x)

Разница в том, что сотни в несколько раз больше, чем сотня. То есть сотни раз — это сильнее.

Мне кажется, что "сотни раз" звучит после глагола.
Сравнить:
*Делал это сотни раз.

Сотни раз делал это.*
А в данном случае — перед глаголом — лучше звучит "сотню раз". Можно заменить на:
*Он уже сто раз пожалел о содеянном.* || И "сто" как-то лучше и устойчивее звучит.

На звучание оказывает влияние форма глагола (совершенная/несовершенная):
*сотню раз пожалел;

жалел сотни раз*.
Почему? Несовершенная форма глагола подразумевает многократное повторение действия. То есть лучше подходит при большем количестве повторов.